# Insert Only One Record In MYSQL database using php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, validation

i am working on a project where i want to insert only one record in a specific time.

For Example: in the project client rate a contractor only once.(when the construction is in working) once he rated he cannot rate second time whatsoever.

I checked online but didn't find what i am looking for.

**Now I have 2 Ideas.**

1- Either insert checkboxes and make them disable permanently, once the rating is done(with server side validation).

2- Rate according to numbers (like 7/10) and display them.

which one is batter strategy to opt.

**Code Part:**

***CheckBox Solution Code***(no solution available on google on serverside validation):

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

<p>Click the "Try it" button to disable the checkbox.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Also checked this on stackoverflow (but this is not i am looking for):

[an example serverside solution link][1]

***Number Solution:***

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Rate Your Contractor (Out Of 10)</td><td><input id="intLimitTextBox"></td></tr>
</table>

<script>

function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
  ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {
    textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      } else {
        this.value = "";
      }
    });
  });
}

// Install input filters.
setInputFilter(document.getElementById("intLimitTextBox"), function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value) && (value === "" || parseInt(value) <= 10); });

</script>
```

Is There any php way(or both ways) to implement the solution of my problem?

PS: i am not very expert in web devolepment, sorry if any mistake i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :** Question has been totally changed !? This is an answer to the original question.

---

Maybe I misunderstood; your title is about php, but your question seems to be an ergonomic one.

For a rating, a current presentation is a list of stars, on which the user clicks on the wanted.

Once user has submitted a rating, I suggest you to have the same presentation, without javascript and without :hover rules.

Maybe changing the colors (yellow when submitting, black or gray when submitted and read-only)

```js
$('.star').on('click', function() {
  var v = $(this).data('value');
  $('input[name="rating"]').val(v);
  $('.star').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active', $this.data('value') <= v);
  });
});
```

```css
/* remove spaces between stars */
.stars {
  font-size:0;
}

.star::after {
  content:"☆";
  display:inline;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

/* by default, only fills active stars */
.stars:not(:hover) .star.active::after,
.stars:hover .star::after {
  content:"★";
}

/* unfill stars following the current hovered */
.stars:hover .star:hover ~ .star::after {
  content:"☆";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="stars">
  <input type="hidden" name="rating" value="" />
  <span class="star" data-value="1"></span>
  <span class="star" data-value="2"></span>
  <span class="star" data-value="3"></span>
  <span class="star" data-value="4"></span>
  <span class="star" data-value="5"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: my main question is to insert value only once in the database by a certin user to a certin person.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :** Question has been totally changed !? This is an answer to the original question.

---

I'll try to answer your second question, then, but it is somehow vague...

**Rendering the form :**

Check if a submission exists for this user.

If yes, render the rating read-only with the value.
(If the rating is the only field you have, don't even render the  tag)

If no, show the form submittable.

**Handling submission** :

On handling submission, check if a submission exists for this user.

If it already exists, return an error (user has tried to trick you)
Otherwise, add a new one.